# Google Spreadsheet, how to get a column filtering by a header value

Tags: google-sheets, filterfunction

To get a *row* from specific value in the first *column* is easy with `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(A:C, A:A = "ROW_89")
```

It will return the whole row which has a "ROW_89" in his column *A*

Now I would like to have the whole **column** which has a "COLUMN_12" in his row *1*.

I'm trying:

```
=FILTER(A:C, 1:1 = "COLUMN_12")
```

But it is not working:

```
Error
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 3. Actual row count: 1, column count: 26.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange thing indeed, but this works:

```
=FILTER(A:C, A1:C1 = "COLUMN_12")
```